# I have an issue with VScode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have an issue with VSCode Editor 
I see a black Box on the side how can I hide it?

it's the first time I can see it

[image: VS]
[image: 2]

Comment: What extension gives you those gradient tab underlines? I really like them.

Comment: it's synthwave84 theme

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better question to ask on their issue tracker rather than here? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's an issue with your current theme. Changing the current theme should fix the problem.

Comment: it's Not sadly!

Comment: if you have the last release "update" tell me if you have faced the same issue with vscode?

Comment: VS Code v1.40.1 does not have this problem. Does this happen with all extensions disabled?